# How can i enable mouse scroll up/down for attribute list

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, dropdown-attribute, list-view

How can i enable mouse rollover on attribute list for up/down list of attributes.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by css, in your attribute container you can set a height. To show the scrollbar, use overflow:scroll

so say you have a block like this:

```
<div>
 <h1> Scrollbar</h1>
  <ul>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

this would be the css:

```
ul{
 max-height:100px;
 overflow:scroll;
```

}

Comment: Its working in my localhost but not  working my live site, how can i clear this error ?

Comment: You will need to clear your magento and browser cache

Comment: I did what you told, but not working..

Comment: can you share a link?